# France Airport Transit Visa for Indian Passport Holders

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, cuba, cdg

I will be traveling from India to Cuba with an connecting flight at Paris CDG airport to Cuba. The layover is 7hrs. Do I need a transit visa for the layover at Paris Airport?

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket/booking? Do you have checked bags?

Answer (score 0):

According to Timatic https://www.timaticweb2.com Indian citizens can transit without a visa, providing you meet the following conditions:

“ Passengers transiting through Paris (CDG), arriving from a non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight within 24 hours to a third country which is not a Schengen Member State. They must:

- stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
- have documents required for their next destination.”

This means both flights must be on the same ticket/booking (or not have any checked bags), otherwise you’ll need a visa to go through passport control to reclaim bags and re-check them.

Comment: @jcaron Thanks, I’ve amended my answer to include this. Although I think the duplicate you’ve flagged is probably the preferred answer

Comment: Actually, if they go through passport control they need a full visa, IIRC there are no longer any transit visas in the Schengen Area (except ATVs).